# How can I save this JSON in mongoDB?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jongo

I need save this JSON: `{edbff2886c8ca7aa1bd02b092aa03930.zip=T001.zip}`. It's from a `Map<String,String>`. Why isn't possible?

```
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "updatedExisting" : false , "err" : "The dotted field 'edbff2886c8ca7aa1bd02b092aa03930.zip' in 'filenameMap.edbff2886c8ca7aa1bd02b092aa03930.zip' is not valid for storage." , "code" : 57}
```

Query

```
public Validacao update(String id, Validacao validacao) {
        mongoCollection.update("{_id : #}", id)
                .with("{$set: #}", validacao);
        return validacao;
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, to start with... you need quotes around the key and value. Although the exception suggests it's a slightly different restriction within MongoDB...

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the casting lol

Comment: @JonSkeet Please add your comment as a response to be able to vote.

Comment: I'd already put an answer with the important MongoDB-specific part... I've updated it with the "this isn't valid JSON"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 {edbff2886c8ca7aa1bd02b092aa03930.zip=T001.zip}
```

isn't valid JSON to start with. You'd need quotes around the field name and the value.

However, even that wouldn't be enough. From the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/):

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or null characters, and they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e. $). See [Dollar Sign Operator Escaping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-dollar-sign-escaping) for an alternate approach.

Now, depending on what *other* characters your field name might have, you could potentially replace all dots with something else before storing - or you may need some sort of escaping mechanism.